# Windows 7 copy User folder

Tags: windows-7, security, user-accounts

I damaged the hard drive in my laptop and had to replace it with a new one. I purchased a device that allows me to connect my damaged hard-drive with a USB port just like an external hard-drive. I can see all the folders/directories but I am denied access when trying to copy my user folder. What am I supposed to do?

Comment: What about NTFS permissions on the forlder ?

Comment: Right click the folder, go to properties and see whether the size of the folder and count displays. Also, navigate to security tab and refer permissions

Answer (score 1):

Download any Linux Live CD (I prefer Ubuntu or Linux Mint) and Boot your system using it. You can access all files and folders from that. And simply use it to move files to your other device.

[Follow this quick article](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/use-ubuntu-live-cd-to-backup-files-from-your-dead-windows-computer/)

Also you can create a Bootable USB instead of a CD/DVD using [Universal USB Installer](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/).

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can just start the file explorer (or any file manager) with admin rights and it will work. Do it this way

[image]

[http://i.imgur.com/BaruIrV.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2OtLM.png)

If not, you may need to take ownership of the folders first in properties / security / advanced / owner